# is LASSO's path deterministic? if yes, it is decided by what? if not, can we control it somehow?

Tags: linear-model, lasso

I am working on LASSO and I don't fully understand how the path works:

Where does the path start? does it start from the feature that gives the biggest variance of prediction?

How does LASSO select which feature to add next?

Is the path (robustly) deterministic? By robust I mean, when I use a random subset of my data, the path should be fairly similar --- if not identical. If the path is not robust, then LASSO's outcome would be quite random, correct? Then we have to rely heavily on CV to make sure that the model is really predictive.

Comment: Look at the Lasso section of:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_methods_for_learning#Lasso_regularization
It's a generalized form of gradient descent.  It is deterministic.

Comment: from the perspective you're looking at this, it might be interesting to read about LARS

Answer (score 3):

LASSO is deterministic when applied to any single data sample from a population but it may select different predictors when applied to a different sample from the same population.

As shown in the [link provided by @user18764](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_methods_for_learning#Lasso_regularization) in a comment, LASSO trades off the mean-square prediction error against a penalty proportional to the sum of the absolute values of the regression coefficients. So, as the penalty on the coefficients is relaxed from infinity, LASSO necessarily starts with the feature that has the strongest single-variable relation to outcome. As the penalty is further relaxed the feature that makes the next best contribution is added. Features entered at early stages might be removed later in some cases, but the path to any final chosen penalty level is deterministic on that data sample.

The confusion enters when you take another sample from the underlying population and the predictive features are correlated. Then there is no assurance that the features most closely related to outcome in the new sample will be the same as those in the first sample. You might have similar predictive value in a model built on the second sample, but the specific predictors chosen could be different.

One good way to evaluate this issue is to repeat the entire LASSO model building process (including choice of penalty) on multiple bootstrap samples from your data and see (1) the variability of feature choices among the multiple models and (2) the predictive value of the multiple models when applied to the original complete data set. It's quite possible to have variability in feature choices and still have reasonably good predictive value.

Comment: thanks a lot! this is similar to what I observed in my work: the feature choices are not static, while the predictive performance is quite stable though. However, it makes me feel uneasy when I put something so 'dynamic' into our production environment.

Comment: @user152503 : Ridge regression might make you feel better if you don't have an enormous number of predictors. It naturally tends to treat correlated predictors together while keeping all of them to some level in the model. Don't know that it will improve predictive performance, but it might make you and your colleagues feel less uneasy. Try it on multiple bootstrap samples, looking at the variance of final regression coefficients among models as well as performance on the original data.